# How to detect data-value from input type=file “change” from the selected button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we click on Button 1 or Button 2, trigger the input-file and find trigger is comes from which button using input-file `data-value` on change event

```
<input type="file" id="upload" data-value="">
<button id="button1">button 1</button>
<button id="button2">button 2</button>

$("document").ready(function(){

  $("#upload").change(function() {
    alert($('#upload').data('value'));
  });

$('#button1').click(function(e) { $('#upload').attr('data-value', 'BUTTON 1').trigger('click');});

$('#button2').click(function(e) { $('#upload').attr('data-value', 'BUTTON 2').trigger('click');});

});
```

But here `alert($('#upload').data('value'))` always showing first time button click value.

means when we click on Button 2, alert showing Button 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `data('value', 'BUTTON 1')` instead of `attr('data-value', 'BUTTON 1')`

same for button 2